# How can I resolve the problem that causes this error "Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"?

Tags: r

I made this account just for this. While I was preparing for my econometrics exam, i ran into an error message saying "Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double". This happened while I was trying to rid my model of heteroscedasticity. My code looks like this:

```
>residualsq<-modell$residuals^2
>modelresidualsq<-lm(residualsq~X+Z+W+Q)
>estimatedresidualsq<-modelresidualsq$fitted.values
>a<-as.numeric(estimatedresidualsq>0)
```

This is when I get the error message. Can anyone help me? Also, dont bother with going into detail why is there a problem, cause I really dont understand the ins and outs of R.

Comment: There is something weird here: ```(estimatedresidualsq`enter code here`>0)```. Is it lacking a ```$```?

Comment: thats just an error in my editing, there is nothing like that in the code. Thank you for bringing it to my attention, I will correct it.

Comment: Could you please add a ```dput(estimatedresidualsq```? Using different data, I could not replicate your error. It produces ```a``` without any error.

Comment: There was some problem with my code, i managed to figure it out. Thank you anyways!